# How do I configure or set up the tridion-powershell-modules in PowerShell?

Tags: core-service, powershell

I came across the [tridion-powershell-modules project](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-powershell-modules/). It offers some handy PowerShell commands which help setting up a CoreService connection and some examples like listing the publication.

What do I need to do to be able to use those commands in PowerShell

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Install the module

- Get the .psm1, .psd1 and DLL files from the [project](http://code.google.com/p/tridion-powershell-modules/source/browse/#svn/trunk). You can also copy the CoreService DLL from the %TRIDION_HOME%bin\client\CoreService folder on your Content Manager
- Create a directory <s>`C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\CoreService`</s>  C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Tridion-CoreService
- Copy the `.psm1`, `.psd1` and `.dll` files in that directory
- Restart any open PowerShell consoles and the Modules are available
- Run <s>`Import-Module CoreService`</s> `Import-Module Tridion-CoreService`
- Run the <s>`Get-TridionCoreServiceInfo`</s> `Get-TridionCoreServiceSettings` to test if you can use the CoreService module. This will not yet contact the Core Service.

Test the connection to the Core Service

- Set the Tridion Content Manager server hostname with <s>`Set-TridionCoreServiceHost cme.server.hostname`</s> `Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings cme.server.hostname 2013-SP1` where "cme.server.hostname" is your server's hostname. The module will default to localhost.
- See if you can access the Core Service by doing a simple operation: `Get-TridionUser -Verbose`. The "-Verbose" will output in verbose mode so you can see what is going on in more detail...
- Now the connection works you can try more commands like `Get-TridionPublications | Select-Object Id, Title` to list the publication id and title of all publications.

MSDN [explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the options we have to install the module.

*EDIT: updated answer with steps to install and steps to test try the module and the connection to the Core Service*

*EDIT: added `Import-Module CoreService` to the instructions, the module will not work without that*

*EDIT: updated commands to match new version of the tridion-powershell-modules*

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out. I shared the code, but not instructions on how to use it. I should add this to the project page!

Comment: yes please add it together with a usage example. the code is pretty easy to read by the way it's just my lack knowledge on PowerShell. I had to change the event in the code to use it on Tridion 2013.

Comment: As you know from our talk yesterday, I have since added support for the later versions of Tridion. I already had it locally, just forgot to update the repository (oops!). I'll add some setup and usage info to the project page.

Comment: works great! i.e. Get-TridionPublications | Select-Object Id, Title

Comment: Wish I could double up-vote both your question and your answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

The **tridion-powershell-modules** project moved to GitHub: https://github.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules

It now is a one-liner to install the module

```
 wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pkjaer/tridion-powershell-modules/master/Installation/Install.ps1" | iex
```

Antother thing which changed is the prerequisites: the new version requires Powershell 3.0.

Comment: The installer File is missing - 404

Comment: It works for me -- perhaps it's a cache or DNS issue?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, (but not a method officially supported by Peter Kjaer). If you are comfortable with getting things running your own way, you might find it interesting to pull directly from GIT. I have my WindowsPowerShell directory in a GIT repository anyway, and I've [blogged here about how to manage the module as a GIT submodule](http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/managing-the-tridion-core-service-powershell-module-as-a-git-submodule).