# Powershell: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: 2011, powershell

I have followed instructions to install Tridion Powershell modules as per this post: [How do I configure or set up the tridion-powershell-modules in PowerShell?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3641/how-do-i-configure-or-set-up-the-tridion-powershell-modules-in-powershell/3643#3643).

I have set the Execution Policy to `Unrestricted` and set the Tridion version to "2011-SP1"

```
 Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings -version "2011-SP1"
```

When I try to run `Get-TridionItem "tcm:4-2151"` I get the following error:

```
> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Tridion-CoreService\Items.psm1:130 char:26
+             $client.Close <<<< () | Out-Null;
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Close:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Tridion Powershell error screenshot]

Here are my Tridion settings:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-TridionCoreServiceSettings

ModuleVersion  : 1.2.0.0
Version        : 2011-SP1
UserName       : TRIDION\Administrator
AssemblyPath   : C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Tridion-CoreService\Clients\Tridion.Content
             Manager.CoreService.Client.2011sp1.dll
ClassName      : Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.SessionAwareCoreServiceClient
ConnectionType : Default
HostName       : localhost
EndpointUrl    : http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/wsHttp
```

What is the cause of the problem and how do I resolve it?

## -- UPDATE --

I've gotten the latest code as per @Peter's comment and now receive a clear error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-TridionItem "tcm:4-2151-16" 
Get-TridionCoreServiceClient : There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/wsHt tp that could accept the message.  This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if p resent, for more details. At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Tridion-CoreService\Items.psm1:116 char:41
+         $client = Get-TridionCoreServiceClient <<<< ;
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Get-TridionCoreServiceClient
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Dominic is right that the code should check if $client is null before calling the Close method. I'll update it in a second. Most likely, you are getting some other error but the finally block throws this exception which masks the original error.

In the future, feel free to add these things as [issues](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-powershell-modules/issues/list) on the Google project itself. And if you're not sure if it's just user error, you can always contact me directly first :)

Comment: Get the latest and try again. Hopefully you will see a more descriptive error.

Comment: With the before-latest version. I could reproduce the "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error when the configuration was in a state that Get-TridionCoreServiceClient would throw an error. So try if Get-TridionCoreServiceClient throws an error.

Comment: I've updated the question with the clear error message after downloading the latest release.  The problem turned out to be that I had to specify my non-default port number in the -hostname.  All works beautifully now.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like $client isn't there any more. You could confirm this with the following test:

```
$client -eq $null
```

It can be as simple a thing as a timeout. Try getting a new $client and see if that works. My own experience is that the client times out pretty quickly, although usually the error is more WCF in style.

Comment: I assume you meant to write "$client -eq $null".

Comment: Yes indeed, Peter. Thanks. I'll edit the answer.