# Exporting permissions with Content Porter 2013 SP1

Tags: content-porter-2013, 2013-sp1, security, permissions, user-rights

Content Porter allows export groups and rights, but I have a question. Can anyone tell me if you can export permissions on folders (read, write, localize, delete) using Content Porter?

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is non-exportable properties, see: [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B562B17F-6112-43CD-AE4B-84F370B4C4F8)

Comment: Content porter does not do this. You can try and automate the settings of permissions using Tridion PowerShell module though. Refer the following question: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3641/how-do-i-configure-or-set-up-the-tridion-powershell-modules-in-powershell. Hope it helps!